# Getting wrong output when checking if 2 date periods overlap

Tags: java, if-statement, time, boolean, localdate

I am trying to make a function which checks if 2 date periods overlap. For example:

`1 July 2019 - 5th July 2019` and `2nd July 2019 - 4th July 2019` would return `true` as the 2 date periods overlap

`1 July 2019 - 5th July 2019` and `13th July 2019 - 24th July 2019` would return `false` as the 2 date periods don't overlap

I get the wrong answer when I compare these 2 dates
`24 March 2019 - 27 March 2019` and `27 March 2019 - 29 March 2019`. I get the answer `false`. Though the answer should be `true` because I count all days inclusive.

How can I fix this?

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate start1 = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MARCH, 24);
        LocalDate end1 = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MARCH, 27);
        LocalDate start2 = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MARCH, 27);
        LocalDate end2 = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MARCH, 29);

        boolean ans = dateOverlaps(start1, end1, start2, end2);
        System.out.println(ans);

    }

    public static boolean dateOverlaps(LocalDate start1, LocalDate end1, LocalDate start2, LocalDate end2) {
        return start2.isBefore(end1) && end2.isAfter(start1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @OleV.V. I don't think you can do that using the LocalDate functions?

Comment: Note that Guava has a `Range` class which can do this kind of comparison for you

Comment: @smac89 I don't want to use other libraries

Comment: @T04435 I see where you’re getting at, and the link is helpful. However the code in this question is already trying to implement the algorithm given there, and the ljnk doesn’t seem to explain why it isn’t working correctly in this particular case. So I suggest that it’s not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need *before or on* for the first part of the condition and similarly *on or after* for the second part (since your start and end dates are inclusive). There isn't one method for that, but a couple of ways to put it into code. For example:

```
    return (start2.isBefore(end1) || start2.isEqual(end1)) 
            && (end2.isEqual(start1) || end2.isAfter(start1));
```

With this change your program prints:

> true

Personally I prefer the shorter but also a bit trickier:

```
    return ! (start2.isAfter(end1) || end2.isBefore(start1));
```

The result is the same. I have turned the logic upside down: The periods overlap if neither period 2 comes after period 1 nor the other way around.